# "Manage external tools" not popping up dialog

Tags: gedit

I enabled the "External Tools" plugin for gedit. I clicked on Tools > Manage External Tools, but it didn't pop up a dialog. It did nothing. What did I do wrong? How can I re-install this plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install, if it isn't already, `gir1.2-gtksource-3.0` package:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtksource-3.0
```

Then give your user ownership over GEdit configuration directory:

```
sudo chown YOUR_USERNAME /home/YOUR_USERNAME/.config/gedit
```

Open GEdit and now you should be able to use External tools plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Only this was enough to solve this problem in my PC.

> Then give your user ownership over GEdit configuration directory:
>
> `sudo chown YOUR_USERNAME /home/YOUR_USERNAME/.config/gedit`
>
> Open GEdit and now you should be able to use External tools plugin.

Comment: The `chown` commands looks wrong... Is it possible that the `Open GEdit` belong to the next line?

Comment: Fixed! You were right.