# gedit "Manage External Tools" menu option doesn't appear

Tags: 16.04, gedit

This is not the same question as: ["Manage external tools" not popping up dialog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489453/manage-external-tools-not-popping-up-dialog) where the dialog box doesn't pop-up after selecting *Manage External Tools* from the gedit *Tools* menu.

My problem is the *Manage External Tools* option doesn't appear in the *Tools* menu at all.

I've checked off to use the plug-in within the *Preferences* sub-menu:

[image: gedit external tools.png]

I've even quit and reloaded *gedit* after enabling the plug-in.

My current version is:

```
$ gedit --version
gedit - Version 3.18.3
```

**Does anyone know why the *Manage External Tools* option isn't appearing?**

---

Results of `namei`:

```
$ namei -l ~/.config/gedit/tools
f: /home/rick/.config/gedit/tools
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
drwxr-xr-x rick rick rick
drwx------ rick rick .config
drwxr-xr-x root root gedit
                     tools - No such file or directory
```

---

Based on steeldriver's comment I ran:

```
sudo chown -cR rick:rick /home/rick
```

and all is well now.

Comment: everything OK with .config permissions (e.g. `namei -l ~/.config/gedit/tools`)?

Comment: @steeldriver actually "not OK" I think. I've updated question with results.

Comment: OK so perhaps there was an ill-advised `sudo gedit` at some point? See for example [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

Comment: @steeldriver I asked a question about root owning `/home/rick/.config/gedit` a month ago: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031303/root-owns-some-files-in-home-user-should-i-be-concerned So now it's time to follow the answer and change ownership back. If you care to read the question for reference and then post an answer here on this question, I'll upvote and accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: Before answering . . . did changing the ownership back actually fix the issue?

Comment: @steeldriver I can manage external tools now and run an external tool. The only issue is even though I give the name "gedit-vars" it gets the name "New Tool" and when I later added "shellcheck" it gets the name "New Tool 2". I tried renaming the files `new-tool` and `new-tool-2` on disk but that just makes them disappear from the menu and I have to rename them back.

Comment: @steeldriver To answer your question, yes it works now. The script naming issue I regard as a separate problem unrelated to ownership issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if `gedit` is unable to write to its configuration directory, perhaps because of a directory ownership or permission issue. You can check using `namei` e.g.

```
namei -l ~/.config/gedit/tools
f: /home/steeldriver/.config/gedit/tools
drwxr-xr-x root        root        /
drwxr-xr-x root        root        home
drwxr-xr-x steeldriver steeldriver steeldriver
drwx------ steeldriver steeldriver .config
drwxr-xr-x steeldriver steeldriver gedit
drwxrwxr-x steeldriver steeldriver tools
```

Files and directories below `~` should be owned by you, **not** `root` - the latter is usually a sign of having used `sudo` to run the application previously: see [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications) Find and fix any such issues using `chown` and/or `chmod` as appropriate, as advised in [`root` owns some files in `/home/user` should I be concerned?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031303/root-owns-some-files-in-home-user-should-i-be-concerned)